# Why No [] operator overload for type Result is thrown with char[] array in D?

Tags: d

I was playing around with `std.range` and `std.algorithm` and bumped int the following issue.

```
int[] arr1 = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
char[] arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

auto res1 = arr.enumerate.find!(t => t[0] == 4);
auto res2 = arr1.enumerate.find!(t => t[0] == 4);

assert(typeof(res1).stringof == typeof(res2).stringof);
```

Now, I'd like to access the result of the `find` which is a `[Tuple!(ulong, "index", int, "value")(4, 5), Tuple!(ulong, "index", int, "value")(5, 8)]`.

```
writeln(res1[0][1]); // 5
```

I correctly get `5`. Now, if I do the same to `res2` which is equal to `[Tuple!(ulong, "index", dchar, "value")(4, 'e')]`

```
writeln(res2[0][1]); // Error: no [] operator overload for type Result
```

an exception is thrown (scratching my head). Can you please explain why it works with `int[]` array and does not work with `char[]`?

UPDATE: If I call `res2.array[0][1]`, it works but I would expect the error message to be more revealing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the Phobos library considers int[] to be random access, but char[] to be sequential access only and thus does not have the operator.

OK, why is that? This is what the D community calls "autodecoding". A char[] is a UTF-8 string. Phobos, trying to be helpful, converts those UTF-8 sequences into a series of dchars, which represent Unicode code points.

UTF-8 sequences have variable length. Most English text will have one byte corresponding to one character on screen, but this is not generally true with other languages. Accent marks, for example, may be represented by various two or three byte sequences. (and it gets even more complex in some cases, with various identical visual representations having different internal representations - std.uni.byGrapheme is a part of the Phobos library that is meant to help with this)

Anyway, Phobos - again trying to be helpful even though we all basically universally feel this was a mistaken design now looking back - tries to condense those possibly-multibyte sequences down to one dchar at a time as it loops. Since it cannot know where the N'th dchar is without scanning through the whole string up to that point (since each dchar potentially may have different lengths and you must examine it to know the size), it cannot do this cheaply.

Since the [] operator is supposed to be cheap, O(1) constant time (and constant memory) operation, this implementation is too complex to confirm to the interface and you get the error instead.

The `.array` function just allocates a big buffer and does all the decoding work up-front, instead of on demand, and thus allows random access... but at the cost of both memory and processing time that may not be necessary if you only need to look at a little bit of the result.

Comment: right, but it would so nice to have a different error message for this case.

Comment: yeah i would kinda love it if it was like "no operator because..." but idk how to implement that. Perhaps the library could do `@disable opIndex`... though @disable doesn't let you explain why either, blargh.

Comment: `enumerate` *does* have `static if (isRandomAccessRange!Range) { ElemType opIndex(size_t i) {/*...*/}}`. If this had an `else` clause with `void opIndex()(size_t i) { static assert(false, "Error message");'}`, I think we could have our pie and eat it, too. Of course, `enumerate` is not the only case where this would need to be implemented, and I'm sure there are places that look for the existence of `opIndex` instead of checking if `foo[0]` compiles, so there are some pitfalls.